# I want to get first value on a multi select field

Tags: trigger, formula, formula-field

Hello i want to get the first value selected in a multiselect field
for exemple if i choose in the field : banana , tomoato , kiwi.
i want to get banana

Comment: I notice you tagged this with formula-field. Multiselects are notoriously difficult to work with within formulas so I am not sure this is something you could identify within a formula alone. I think you will need to go the route of using Apex code.

Answer (score 1):

I see similar ask is been addressed here on this link =>
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000Agj5IAC

Where following piece of code made the trick work:

```
List<Integer> intList = new List<Integer>();
Map<Integer, String> keyValMap = new Map<Integer, String>();
for(SelectOption i:listResult){
    intList.add(Integer.valueOf(i.getValue()));
    keyValMap.put(Integer.valueOf(i.getValue()),i.getLabel());
}
intList.sort();
listResult.clear();
for(Integer i:intList){
    listResult.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i),keyValMap.get(i)));
}
```

You can modify it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get this in apex, then you can use following code.
Suppose you have the field name as selectedOptions for the Record Rec1. If you get the selectedOptions and split it then the first element in the list will be the first item which is selected.

```
List<String> selectedItemList = new List<String>();
selectedItemList = Rec1.selectedOptions__c.split(';');
if(!selectedItemList.isEmpty())
{
    System.debug('First Item selected is' +selectedItemList[0]);
}
```